# Display foreign key

Tags: php, laravel

I have 2 tables, the first is **clubs** with 3 fields (id_club, name_club, type_sport_club), the second table is **membres** with 3 fields (id_membre, name_membre, fk_club).

In my folder membres index.blade.php  I get a error message

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Champ 'clubs.id' unknown in where clause (SQL: select * from `clubs` where `clubs`.`id` = 1 limit 1) "

Is it I have forgot anything?

```
<div class="px-content">
    <div class="page-header">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 text-xs-center text-md-left text-nowrap">
          <h1><i class="px-nav-icon ion-android-apps"></i>Liste des enregistrements</h1>
        </div>
        <hr class="page-wide-block visible-xs visible-sm">
        <!-- Spacer -->
        <div class="m-b-2 visible-xs visible-sm clearfix"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="panel">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table">
              <a class="btn btn-sm btn-success" href="{{ route('membres.create') }}">Ajouter</a>
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Name</th>
                  <th>Club</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                @foreach($membres as $membre)
                <tr>
                   <td> {{$membre->name_membre}}</td>
                   <td> {{$membre->club->name_club}}</td> 
                   <td>
                     <form method="POST" action="{{ route('membres.destroy', $membre) }} ">
                    <a class="btn btn-sm btn-warning" href="{{route('membres.edit',$membre->id_membre)}}">Editer</a>
                    @csrf
                    @method('DELETE')
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Deleter</button>
                    </form>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                @endforeach
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
{!! $membres->links() !!}
  </div>
@endsection
```

For information

```
public function up()
     {
         Schema::create('membres', function (Blueprint $table) {
             $table->increments('id_membre');
             $table->string('name_membre');
             $table->integer('fk_club')->unsigned();
             $table->foreign('fk_club')->references('id_club')->on('clubs');
             $table->timestamps();
         });
     }
```

Thank you

Comment: The first thing you tell is is what the columns of the `clubs` table are and the id column is called `id_club` So therefore it should be `clubs.id_club`

Comment: Could we see your controller where you're passing the model to the view?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM clubs WHERE clubs.id_club = 1 LIMIT 1` will do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that you didn't pass the right key when you added the relation on the `Membre` model. It should be something similar to:

```
public function club()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Club', 'fk_club', 'id_club');
}
```

Also, you must update the relation to the `Club` model to:

```
public function membres()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Membres', 'fk_club', 'id_club');
}
```

Comment: Concerning the model membre I have this protected  $fillable = ['name_membre', 'fk_club'];
  
  public function club(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Club', 'fk_club');
  }

Comment: put the other ID too as it differs from the Laravel standards

Comment: @ Matei Mihai: Sorry I don't understand...I have the version 5.6 ... For the { return $this->belongsTo('App\Club', 'fk_club'); } I change by { return $this->belongsTo('App\Club', 'id_club'); } ???

Comment: @anais_stemb look in the answer.. change it to `$this->belongsTo('App\Club', 'fk_club', 'id_club')` you must provide both columns to the relation